# Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. Error while trying to create a form page

Tags: reactjs

A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Seems like everything is in place.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import style from './appStyles.module.css'
class InvoiceData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      StartDate: '',
      EndDate: '',
      Market: 'US'
    };
    this.onChangeHandlerStartDate = this.onChangeHandlerStartDate.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandlerEndDate = this.onChangeHandlerEndDate.bind(this);
    this.onChangeMarket = this.onChangeMarket.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onChangeHandlerStartDate = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      StartDate: event.target.StartDate
    });
  }

  onChangeHandlerEndDate = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      EndDate: event.target.EndDate
    });
  }

  onChangeMarket = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      Market: event.target.Market
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    alert('Requested reprocessing for' + this.state.Market + 'market with startDate :' + this.state.StartDate + 'and EndDate :' + this.state.EndDate)
    event.preventDefault()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.login}>
        <div className={style.form}>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <span className={style.material}></span>
            <label>Invoice Reprocessing</label><br></br><br></br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="StartDate :MM-dd-yyyy" required value={this.state.StartDate} onChange={this.onChangeHandlerStartDate} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="EndDate :MM-dd-yyyy" required value={this.state.EndDate} onChange={this.onChangeHandlerEndDate} />
            <label>Market   : </label>
            <select id="market" required value={this.state.Market} onChange={this.onChangeMarket}>
              &nbps&nbps
              <option value="US">US</option>
              <option value="CA">CA</option>
              <option value="EU">EU</option>
              <option value="JP">JP</option>
            </select><br></br><br></br>
            <button value=
              "Submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default InvoiceData
```

Comment: `event.target.StartDate` (along with the others) will not exist. It's `event.target.value`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @BrianThompson